# Small business tax dates, what is "the date" of a job?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, small-business, business

I work to a tax year that starts on the 6th of April.

I have a number of jobs which before this date are:

- "in the pipeline" i.e. in my order book
- work in progress
- finished not invoiced
- finished and invoiced
- finished, invoiced, cash received

Then, after this date any of these jobs may be (again)

- "in the pipeline" i.e. in my order book
- work in progress
- finished not invoiced
- finished and invoiced
- finished, invoiced, cash received

My question is when splitting my work up into which Tax Year it took place in, which of these actions and dates define what tax year the work took place in? I am based in the UK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really only two options: invoiced, or paid. Everything else is not relevant from a tax or accounting point of view. Of course, if you're invoicing as you go along or collecting deposits once things are in your order books, then that amount of money is relevant.

Working things out according to when you invoice is called working on an accrual basis. Working it out according to when you get paid is called working on a cash basis. [Wikipedia explains the distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cash_and_accrual_methods_of_accounting), which also applies to your expenses: when did you incur them (get the bill) vs when you did you pay it. In some jurisdictions and for some kinds of companies, you can choose which of these two bases to work on (but no other basis.)

There is advice on the UK government website about [keeping your accounts](https://www.gov.uk/prepare-file-annual-accounts-for-limited-company/prepare-annual-accounts). It includes a link to a PDF and on page 15 of that 100 page PDF it states:

> 2.14 The financial statements, with the exception of cash flow information, shall be prepared on the accruals basis of accounting. HENCE, ALL INCOME AND CHARGES RELATING TO THE FINANCIAL YEARTO WHICH THE ACCOUNTS RELATE MUST BE TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT, WITHOUT
>   REGARD TO THE DATE OF PAYMENT OR RECEIPT.

That seems pretty clear to me. When you invoice. Period.